# Formal proof that if $a-b = \frac{a-b}{ab}$, $a-b$ has to be zero.

Tags: proof-writing, formal-proofs

Just out of interest, how would I provide a proof that if $a-b = \frac{a-b}{ab}$, then $a$ has to be equal to $b$? It appears really logical, I just want to know how to formally prove it. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It's not true.  If $a=2, b=\frac 12$ then $ab=1$ and $a-b\neq 0$.  If you had intended to restrict the possible values of $a,b$ you should do so explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu)'s comment, it's not true, but this is true:

$a-b=\dfrac{a-b}{ab}\implies (a-b)ab=a-b \implies (a-b)(ab-1)=0\implies a=b$ or $ab=1$

Comment: Thanks. And if I restricted to $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, I could exclude $ab = 1$, right?

Comment: If $a,b\in\Bbb N$ and $ab=1,$ then $a=b=1,$ so $a-b=0$